# Append values to a set in Python

Tags: python, set, append

How do I add values to an existing `set`?

Answer (score 558, accepted):

```
your_set.update(your_sequence_of_values)
```

e.g, `your_set.update([1, 2, 3, 4])`. Or, if you *have* to produce the values in a loop for some other reason,

```
for value in ...:
    your_set.add(value)
```

But, of course, doing it in bulk with a single [`.update`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset.update) call is faster and handier, when otherwise feasible.

Comment: `.add` adds a single item, `.update` adds several items. Is that correct?

Comment: @ThorSummoner Yes, `.add` expects a single hashable type, while `.update` expects an iterable object

Comment: If you add a string with update, it will add one item per character in your string because it's an iterable!

Comment: It's indeed important to note that strings, as "whole" objects, should be added with `.add`, not `.update`, I recently faced quite a sneaky bug on account of this small detail.

Comment: `add` and `update` change the set object, you can call `{*a, *b}` to return a new set object

Answer (score 447):

Define a set

```py
a = set()
```

Use [`add`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset.add) to append single values

```py
a.add(1)
a.add(2)
```

Use [`update`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset.update) to add elements from tuples, sets, lists or frozen-sets

```py
a.update([3, 4])
```

```
>>> print(a)
{1, 2, 3, 4}
```

Note: Since set elements must be hashable, and lists are considered mutable, you cannot `add` a list to a set. You also cannot `add` other sets to a set. You can however, add the elements from lists and sets as demonstrated with the `.update` method.

Comment: Really you edited my answer with the same answer? Thanks for contributing??

Answer (score 152):

You can also use the `|` operator to concatenate two sets (**union** in set theory):

```
>>> my_set = {1}
>>> my_set = my_set | {2}
>>> my_set
{1, 2}
```

Or a shorter form using `|=`:

```
>>> my_set = {1}
>>> my_set |= {2}
>>> my_set
{1, 2}
```

**Note:** In versions prior to Python 2.7, use `set([...])` instead of `{...}`.

Comment: If you have a list of sets `my_sets`, then you can do `big_set = my_sets[0].union(*my_sets[1:])` to combine them all

Answer (score 47):

Use `update` like this:

```
keep.update(newvalues)
```

Answer (score 19):

This question is the first one that shows up on Google when one looks up "Python how to add elements to set", so it's worth noting explicitly that, if you want to add a whole string to a set, it should be added with `.add()`, not `.update()`.

Say you have a string `foo_str` whose contents are `'this is a sentence'`, and you have some set `bar_set` equal to `set()`.

If you do
`bar_set.update(foo_str)`, the contents of your set will be `{'t', 'a', ' ', 'e', 's', 'n', 'h', 'c', 'i'}`.

If you do `bar_set.add(foo_str)`, the contents of your set will be `{'this is a sentence'}`.

Comment: upvoted, for clarifying the whole picture.

Answer (score 2):

The way I like to do this is to convert both the original set and the values I'd like to add into lists, add them, and then convert them back into a set, like this:

```
setMenu = {"Eggs", "Bacon"}
print(setMenu)
> {'Bacon', 'Eggs'}
setMenu = set(list(setMenu) + list({"Spam"}))
print(setMenu)
> {'Bacon', 'Spam', 'Eggs'}
setAdditions = {"Lobster", "Sausage"}
setMenu = set(list(setMenu) + list(setAdditions))
print(setMenu)
> {'Lobster', 'Spam', 'Eggs', 'Sausage', 'Bacon'}
```

This way I can also easily add multiple sets using the same logic, which gets me an `TypeError: unhashable type: 'set'` if I try doing it with the `.update()` method.

Comment: Converting to lists and back is a lot of unnecessary overhead and seems to defeat the purpose of sets.  Consider the answer by @nyuszika7h as well as the solution in comments (ill copy here):
`big_set = my_sets[0].union(*my_sets[1:])`

Answer (score 2):

I just wanted to add a quick note here. So I was looking for the fastest method among the three methods.

1. Using the set.add() function
2. Using the set.update() function
3. Using the "|" operator function.

I find it out that to add either a single value or multiple values to a set you have to use the set.add() function. It is the most efficient method among the others.

So I ran a test and Here is the result:

1. `set.add()`  Took:  0.5208224999951199
2. `set.update()` Took:
   0.6461397000239231 `
3. "|" operator` Took:  0.7649438999942504

PS: If you want to know more the analysis.

Check here : [Fastest way to append values to set](https://www.alixaprodev.com/2022/07/append-values-to-set-in-python.html).

Answer (score 0):

For me, in Python 3, it's working simply in this way:

```
keep = keep.union((0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10))
```

I don't know if it may be correct...

Answer (score 0):

```
keep.update((0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10))
```

Or

```
keep.update(np.arange(11))
```

Comment: Your answer does not improve upon the existing answer from @sberry which was posted 9 years before your answer.