# Generate string set from csv file in Python

Tags: python, pandas, set

Please don't flag my answer instantaniously, because I searched several other questions that didn't solve my problem, like [this.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3392354/append-values-to-a-set-in-python)

I'm trying to generate a python set of strings from a csv file. The printed pandas dataframe of the loaded csv file has the following structure:

```
   0
0  me
1  yes
2  it
```

For a project I need this to be formatted to look like this

```
STOPWORDS = {'me', 'yes', 'it'}
```

I tried to do this by the following code.

```
import pandas as pd

df_stopwords = pd.read_csv("C:/Users/Jakob/stopwords.csv", encoding = 'iso8859-15', header=-1)

STOPWORDS = {}
for index, row in df_stopwords.iterrows():
    STOPWORDS.update(str(row))

print(STOPWORDS)
```

However, I get this error:

```
dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 1; 2 is required
```

When I use the `STOPWORDS.update(str(row))` I get the this error:

```
'dict' object has no attribute 'add'
```

Thank you all in advance!

Comment: Do you need a `dict` or a `set`?

Comment: what about: `set(df_stopwords[0])`

Comment: Just do something like `set(df.values.ravel())`

Comment: @nixon please post this as an answer. I want to give you the credit for this! Solved my problem. At all: Please upvote! ;-P

Comment: @YOLO Your solution worked perfectly as well. I want to accept both your answers! :D Big Thank You!

Comment: the reason why your original code did not work: `STOPWORDS = {}` initializes a dictionary. What you want is: `STOPWORDS=set()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can directly create a `set` from the values in the dataframe with:

```
set(df.values.ravel())
{'me', 'yes', 'it'}
```

Answer (score 1):

A dictionary is a mapping of keys and values. Like an object in many other languages. Since you need it as a set, define it as a set. Don't change it to a set later.

```
import pandas as pd

df_stopwords = pd.read_csv("C:/Users/Jakob/stopwords.csv", encoding = 'iso8859-15', header=-1)

STOPWORDS = set()
for index, row in df_stopwords.iterrows():
    STOPWORDS.add(str(row))

print(STOPWORDS)
```

Comment: I need the curly brackets. That is the reason why I can't use a list. Thank you!

Comment: Why would you need the curly brackets? Python only uses them for specific things.

Comment: I use this set as an input to the wordcloud library that requires a set of words that shouldn't be shown in the word cloud. It is not accepting lists.

Comment: If you are formatting it into a string, you could do this: `with_curly_brackets = str(STOPWORDS).replace("[", "{").replace("]", "}")`

Comment: Ah... I see. I'm updating my answer with the more Pythonic way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you need to convert the values in your column as a list and then use the list as your stop words.

```
stopwords = df_stopwords['0'].tolist()
--> ['me', 'yes', 'it']
```

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the accepted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7837722/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-loop-through-dataframes-with-pandas). You might wanna use `itertuples()` since it is faster.

```
STOPWORDS = set()
for index, row in df_stopwords.itertuples():
    STOPWORDS.add(row)

print(STOPWORDS)
```